# Porting my DirectX application to other machines

Tags: c++, windows, build, directx, release

I have recently created a 3d environment in DirectX and have made a small 'demo' app. I created the app on Win 7, VS 2013, using the Windows 8 SDK. I would like to put a build of the app on my website for all to use. I'm unsure however, of how exactly to do this. When I build a x64 release build and try to run it on my Win 10 desktop or my brothers win 7 desktop it will not run. It simply crashes as soon as I click on the application saying "GraphicsProject.exe has stopped working".  The .exe runs fine on the laptop I created it on (release build outside of VS) and on another Win 7 computer.

The computers that didn't work have DirectX installed (DX11+) and I have installed the C++ and C runtime libraries on them. What else could be causing the crash or could it be directly related to my code?

I realize the problem could have multiple causes but I'm unsure of what information to look at it in order to narrow the issue down. If you need any additional information just ask!

Comment: It's a bug in your code somewhere. Make sure you're checking all return values for errors. Use a debugger to see where it crashed and maybe figure out why.

Comment: How can I debug with a release build outside of VS though? Also, what could cause the code to run fine on one x64 Win 7 and not another?

Comment: You can download and install Microsoft's Debugging Tools for Windows on the machine, though it might be simpler to just install Visual Studio. Any number of things could have caused the crash. Using a debugger can help you find the problem.

Comment: What @RossRidge said is true, but try to debug it without using Visual Studio. Maybe the error happens because your program depends on something that VS installs automatically, so installing it could hide the problem.

Comment: if you're not using advanced techologies like tessellation, try to run on shader model 4_0

Comment: Is the Visual CRT installed? Are all dependencies bundled? Are shaders and assets loaded for the correct path *(on another computer paths don't match so they must be relative to binary path)*?

Answer (score 0):

From experience on this exact problem (getting a DirectX release app to work on non-development machine):

Don't install any MS debuggers on the release machine. That taints the test machine, and you will only prolong the problem. As Ross stated, there is something crashing in your code that the debugging environment is compensating for, or some environment/graphics card setting mismatch (possibly a shader mismatch/ outdated device driver on the test machine).

Do start to build logging into your application. Do it while it's in development at the early stages, create compiler directives(#ifdef) to turn them on and off, and use multiple levels of debugging (verbose, warning, errors, information). Write out each function name you enter, parameters sent, results passed back. Learn to love logging.

This method guarantees that you do not run out of test machines, or brothers that start complaining that you are installing too much stuff on their machine to test your software. The number of iterations you have to do to pinpoint the problem is directly proportional to the amount of logging you include.